# R: calculate mean of zoo object at particular times

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have 3 days long time series (data) sampled every minute (60*24*3 values):

```
require(zoo)
t<-seq(as.POSIXlt("2015/02/02 00:01:00"),as.POSIXlt("2015/02/04 24:00:00"), length.out=60*24*3)
d<-seq(1,2, length.out=60*24*3)
data<-zoo(d,t)
```

I would like to calculate:

1. Mean values (over three days span) for every minute of the hour assuming that all hours are equal. In this case I should have  60 values in the output with time stamps:

01:00, 02:00, ..., 60:00. Each mean must be calculated over 24x3=72 values, since we have 72 hours in three days long time series.

2. Same as above but additionally tracking hours:

00:01:00, 00:02:00, ..., 23:60:00.  Each mean will be calculated over three values, since we have three days long time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two both create zoo series use `aggregate.zoo`.  The index of the resulting zoo series will be of chron `"times"` class.

```
library(chron) # "times" class

aggregate(data, times(format(time(data), "00:%M:00")), mean)

aggregate(data, times(format(time(data), "%H:%M:00")), mean)
```

If its OK that the index is of class `"character"` then `times` can be omitted in which case chron is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `data.table` and `lubridate`:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
##
Dt <- data.table(
  Data=as.numeric(data),
  Index=index(data))
##
min_dt <- Dt[
  ,list(Mean=mean(Data)),
  by=list(Minute=minute(Index))]
##
hmin_dt <- Dt[
  ,list(Mean=mean(Data)),
  by=list(Hour=hour(Index),
          Minute=minute(Index))]
##
R> head(min_dt)
   Minute     Mean
1:      1 1.493170
2:      2 1.493401
3:      3 1.493633
4:      4 1.493864
5:      5 1.494096
6:      6 1.494327
##
R> head(hmin_dt)
   Hour Minute     Mean
1:    0      1 1.333411
2:    0      2 1.333642
3:    0      3 1.333874
4:    0      4 1.334105
5:    0      5 1.334337
6:    0      6 1.334568
```

---

**Data:**

```
library(zoo)
t <- seq(
  as.POSIXlt("2015/02/02 00:01:00"),
  as.POSIXlt("2015/02/04 24:00:00"), 
  length.out=60*24*3)
d <- seq(1,2,length.out=60*24*3)
data <- zoo(d,t)
```